# setTimeout() not working properly

Tags: javascript, settimeout

Here is my code

```
(function() {
    (function DeleteREG(i) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            if (i > 0) {
                setTimeout(function stop_() {
                    alert(i);
                }, 2000);
                setTimeout(function() {
                    i--;
                    DeleteREG(i);
                }, 800);
            }
        }, 4000);
    })(5);
})();
```

According to the code it should alert at `i=5,4,3,2,1`.But it alerts at `i=4,3,2,1,0`.Can anyone please explain me why it is not working?what should be rectified to the code to work properly?Same thing happens for the following code also

```
(function() {
    (function DeleteREG(i) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            if (i > 0) {
                setTimeout(function stop_() {
                    alert(i);
                }, 2000);

                    i--;
                    DeleteREG(i);
            }
        }, 4000);
    })(5);
})();
```

And please explain me the solution in written format.How to get rid of this problem?

Comment: The second timeout will run before the first, so `i` will be decremented before calling `alert`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `setTimeout`, your code doesn't stop.

Those two functions defined here :

```
            setTimeout(function stop_() {
                alert(i);
            }, 2000);
            setTimeout(function() {
                i--;
                DeleteREG(i);
            }, 800);
```

They're called `2000` and `800` ms after **the same moment**. That's why `i--` comes before the `alert` of the first callback.

A "solution" might be to chain the first of those callback in the second one :

```
(function() {
    (function DeleteREG(i) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            if (i > 0) {
                setTimeout(function stop_() {
                    console.log(i);
                    setTimeout(function() {
                      i--;
                      DeleteREG(i);
                  }, 80);
                }, 200);

            }
        }, 400);
    })(5);
})();
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.Could you please write the revised code?

Comment: Is there any book or website which will teach me all about this?Actually I am new to this language.So,Can you please recommend some books or sites for this?Please reply.Again if I want to contact you if I have some doubt ,then how can I contact you?

Comment: @Satya This is probably the best documentation of JS : https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript

Comment: +1 for MDN docs, one book I would recommend is "Professional JavaScript for Web Developers" by Nicholas C. Zakas, and of course the ["Crockford on JavaScript"](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL7664379246A246CB) playlist

Comment: Thank you [dystroy](http://stackoverflow.com/users/263525/dystroy) and [Stefan Baiu](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2844991/stefan-baiu) for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

the functions that are passed to the 2 `setTimeout`s are created in the same execution scope ( an execution scope is created when a function is executed ) that's why they share the **same** `i` variable. The second callback will be fired before the first, therefore altering the `i` variable.

`setTimeout` pushes a message into a message queue after x milliseconds have passed, x being the time you passed as the second parameter. Anyway, the callback passed to setTimeout will always run after the current stack has been finished. This happens even if you pass 0 milliseconds ( read more details [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/EventLoop)).

UPDATE: I'm not sure what are you trying to achieve, but if you want to count from 5 to 1, this would do:

```
var delay = 1000;

function doStuff (i) {
    if ( i > 0 ) {
        alert(i);

        i -= 1;
        setTimeout(function () {
            doStuff(i);
        }, delay);
    }
}
doStuff(5);
```

Comment: no problem, please follow the link I've provided. It will help you better understand the event loop mechanism, which is one of the fundamental concepts that need to be grasped when working with JS. Sadly, most people don't bother to learn the language and they eventually end up with code that is very confusing to look at.

Comment: Ok.I will sure follow that link.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Check Out if you're not using throttling options on chrome. It can simulate a slow device, changing timing for intervals.